# When should TAGs be preferred over BRANCHING and vice versa (in CVS)?

Tags: version-control, comparison, cvs

I think title should be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tags**

Think of it as a snapshot in time.  I want to be able to go back to that exact point.  However, it will never change.  You do not do a checkin on a tagged element.

Things that can get tagged:

- Releases (major and minor)
- Patches sent to customers
- Bug fixes
- Milestones (alpha, beta, etc...)
- Successful Daily build

**Branches**

The branch will have development performed on it (i.e. checkins).
You might create a branch from a tag (to do a bug fix for example).
You might create a branch to develop a feature and then merge it back to the main trunk.
You might create a branch for a release (minor or major).

The key point is that branches could be modified, and tags **should not be**.

Answer (score 5):

Tags should be used when you want to mark a milestone.  The milestone could be as small as a daily build.

Branches should be used when you want to make changes independently from another branch/trunk.

Answer (score 0):

Branching should also be used for major milestones, such as a releases. This depends on your [branching strategy](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=branching+strategy) though.

Answer (score 0):

Apropos other replies,

We use tags for minor point releases and branches for releases. So for example,

```
v1.0 <-- Branch  
  v1.0.1 <-- Tag  
  v1.0.2 <-- Tag  
v1.1 <-- Branch  
  v1.1.1 <-- Tag  
  v1.1.2 <-- Tag  
v1.2 <-- Branch  
  v1.2.1 <-- Tag  
  v1.2.2 <-- Tag  
v1.3 <-- Branch  
  v1.3.1 <-- Tag  
  v1.3.2 <-- Tag  
v1.4 <-- Branch  
  v1.4.1 <-- Tag  
  v1.4.2 <-- Tag  
v1.5 <-- Branch  
  v1.5.1 <-- Tag  
  v1.5.2 <-- Tag
```

To use a Microsoft analogy, a Branch is a release of Windows (95, XP, Vista, etc) and a tag is a service pack.